To create an alias for grep and to include directories
Frequently I'm using grep to search for some text in a bunch of folders, e.g.
grep --include='*.csv' -nRHI --color=always 'pattern' Folder1 Folder2  

I'd like to create an alias something like
alias MyGrep="grep --include='*.csv' -nRHI --color=always Folder1 Folder2"

so that next time with something to search, I only need to
MyGrep 'pattern'

However this does not work as searching pattern has to come before folder list.
Is there a work-around with alias pls?
ps. I can use a function instead, e.g.
function MyGrep() { grep --include='*.csv' -nRHI --color=always "$@" Folder1 Folder2;}

then I can run
MyGrep pattern

But curious if there's a work-around via alias.

Your edit has come after my answer. You don't need (and shouldn't use) the function keyword to introduce a function unless you're using ksh; just define it directly

You made the best answer to your own question, most notably through the use of "$@". You should make your own answer. Note also that functions don't fork a sub shell. Due to their more general usability ( |, ;, &… ), functions should be prefered to aliases.

Aliases are just direct equivalents to something you type on the command line. If you want interpolation you need to define a function:
MyGrep() { grep --include='*.csv' -nRHI --color=always "$1" Folder1 Folder2 Folder3; }

Use it as your suggested example,
MyGrep 'PatternToSearch'

The definition can go into your ~/.bashrc just like an alias would

Any reason not to use grep ... "$@" instead of grep ... "$1" here? Why limit to only one argument?

Using "$@" allows the set of folders to be extended, which may or may not be appropriate here. In fact it might be justifiable to use "$*" here to support patterns with spaces without quotes (but then that just gets confusing).

@terdon not particularly, no, but the example showed a single argument so I dropped in a single argument placeholder. Sometimes I might do something like re=$1; shift; [ $# -eq 0 ] && set -- Folder1 Folder2 Folder3; grep … "$re" "$@" to allow for overriding the default set of directories to search, but not here

Nah, I was just being dense. $@ wouldn't make sense here, I'm just used to always using it for functions like this, but in this case it would be pointless since grep only takes a single pattern as an argument. So to give it more, you would need to do something more complicated using -e to chain the elements of $@ together etc.
